# setting cookies in node

Tags: node.js, cookies

I want to set a cookie when I login using node. In my frontons I only use js. I'm trying cookie-parser.

In my server.js file I have

```
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
app.use(cookieParser());
```

And a route:

```
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {

    User.find({
            email: req.body.email
        })
        .exec()
        .then(user => {

 bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user[0].password).then(function (result) {

 if (result) {
const token = jwt.sign({
                        email: user[0].email,
                        userId: user[0]._id
                    },

                    process.env.JWT_KEY, {
                        expiresIn: "1h"
                    }
                )

                res.cookie('userToken', token);
                res.render('index', {
                    movies: {}
                });
             })

        })
})
```

I'm testing in another route if the cookie is set using:

```
     console.log('cookies',res.cookies)
```

Console.log gives me an empty object. What am I missing here?

Comment: try to get by using req.cookies

Comment: Use`req.cookies` instead of `res.cookies`. check this link https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-parser.html

Comment: It's undefined.

Comment: You are saying to use req.cookies in the console.log, right

Comment: you want use cookie parser above the router 
Like :  
 app.use(express.cookieParser());
 app.use(app.router);
Then in console use req.cookies